# Add a pin on map at user's location

Tags: swift, xcode

I want add a pin near a user's location.
i can do it  with static coordinate
 but i can't do it  with user's location. I need a button that adds it
i made the button but when i press it it doesn’t  do anything
  and i can't repress the same button
 this is what i tried

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import LocalAuthentication


class ViewController: UIViewController {
//   Per la mappa
    @IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!
    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()


    // FOTOCAMERA
//
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        Map.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    @IBAction func Add(_ sender: Any) {



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)

        var userLocation : CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)


            let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

          Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake ( userLocation.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.title = "urgenza"
        annotation.subtitle = "QUI SI TROVA LA TUA URGENZA"
        Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }
}
```

Comment: You should set the `delegate` for your `locationManager`.

Comment: By the way, this method is going to get called quite a bit. Do you really want to repeatedly add all of those annotations to your map? And, FYI, the map view has a [`showsUserLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation) property that eliminates the need for you to do your own location manager. And if you want to recenter the map on the user, set the [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode).

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d suggest you start your property names with lowercase letter (e.g. `map` or `mapView` rather than `Map`). Class, struct, and enum type names start with uppercase letter. Properties, variables, etc. always start with lowercase letter.

Comment: yes i really need that  But i dont get what you mean , im new on this code.